# Transient instance must be saved before current operation on a @ManytoOne field referencing a non id field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm having this classic problem, but I don't find anyone with the same exact problem anywhere.

These are the two tables in question

```
    Prices            OverrideCategory             
______________       __________________    
|id          |       |id              |
|bandId      |       |storeId         |
|sku         |       |priceCategory   |
|category    |       |overridePrice   |
|oldPrice    |       |reason          |
|newPrice    |       |author          |
|updateUTC   |       |updateUTC       |
______________       __________________
```

This is how I'm mapping this two tables.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "overrideCategory")
public class OverrideCategoryEntity extends Author {

    @Builder
    public OverrideCategoryEntity(@NotNull String reason, @NotNull String author, StoreEntity storeId, PricesEntity priceCategory, @NotNull BigDecimal overridePrice) {
        super(reason, author);
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.priceCategory = priceCategory;
        this.overridePrice = overridePrice;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "storeId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private StoreEntity storeId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "priceCategory", referencedColumnName = "category", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PricesEntity priceCategory;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal overridePrice;
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "prices")
public class PricesEntity extends Price {

    @Builder
    public PricesEntity(@NotNull BigDecimal oldPrice, @NotNull BigDecimal newPrice, BandsEntity bandId, @NotNull String sku, @NotNull String category) {
        super(oldPrice, newPrice);
        this.bandId = bandId;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "bandId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private BandsEntity bandId;

    @NotBlank
    private String sku;

    @NotBlank
    private String category;
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
public class OverrideCategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private final OverrideCategoryRepository repository;


    public OverrideCategoryController(OverrideCategoryRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/categories")
    OverrideCategoryEntity newOverrideCategory(@RequestBody @Valid OverrideCategory overrideCategory) {
        OverrideCategoryEntity entity = modelMapper.map(overrideCategory, OverrideCategoryEntity.class);
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
```

This is my repository

```
public interface OverrideCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<OverrideCategoryEntity, BigInteger> {

}
```

This is the DTO that I use for the endpoint

```
@Data
public class OverrideCategory extends Author {

    @NotNull
    private BigInteger storeId;

    @NotBlank
    private String priceCategory;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 0)
    private BigDecimal overridePrice;

}
```

This is my Json that I'm sending

```
{
    "storeId": 1,
    "priceCategory": "category",
    "overridePrice": 50.23,
    "reason": "reason",
    "author": "author"
}
```

This is the error that I get

```
2019-06-19 15:39:07.850  WARN 27026 --- [nio-8118-exec-1] o.h.a.i.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions    : HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([com.priceengine.domain.PricesEntity#<null>])
    Dependent entities: ([[com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity#<null>]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity.priceCategory])
2019-06-19 15:39:07.910 ERROR 27026 --- [nio-8118-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity.priceCategory -> com.priceengine.domain.PricesEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity.priceCategory -> com.priceengine.domain.PricesEntity] with root cause


org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity.priceCategory -> com.priceengine.domain.PricesEntity; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.priceengine.domain.OverrideCategoryEntity.priceCategory -> com.priceengine.domain.PricesEntity
```

The `prices` table have data, I tried the cascade options, I thought that it could be the mapping between the DTO and the Entities, but the mapping works for other tables that I have. The other tables only have one ***@ManyToOne*** annotation, and they reference the id from the parent table.

This table have two ***@ManyToOne*** relations and one of then is not referencing an `id`, should that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the mapping of the entity.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "overrideCategory")
public class OverrideCategoryEntity extends Author {

    @Builder
    public OverrideCategoryEntity(@NotNull String reason, @NotNull String author, BigInteger storeId, String priceCategory, @NotNull BigDecimal overridePrice) {
        super(reason, author);
        this.storeId = storeId;
        this.priceCategory = priceCategory;
        this.overridePrice = overridePrice;
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "storeId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private StoreEntity storeEntity;

    @JoinColumn(name = "priceCategory", referencedColumnName = "category", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PricesEntity pricesEntity;

    @Column(name = "priceCategory")
    private String priceCategory;

    @Column(name = "storeId")
    private BigInteger storeId;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal overridePrice;
```

I did a lot of testing and everything is working fine, but I don't think this is the right way of mapping my entity. There is any problem of mapping the entity like this?